# What is the shortest way to check a LONG written function for a valid output first (not null), and then to use it several times

Tags: javascript

Using vanilla js, I've put together a one liner that takes a long function, first checks to see if it has a valid value (not null), and if it has a valid value to use that long function several times in a shortened manner.

The code for it is something like this:

```
(x => {if (!x) return; x.style.color='brown'; x.style.fontWeight='600';})(document.evaluate('//ul[@class="main-menu"]//li[text()="About"]', document, null, 9).singleNodeValue;);
```

The html it might work on would be something like this:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

The long way of doing it would be something like this:

```
var x = document.evaluate('//ul[@class="main-menu"]//li[text()="About"]', document, null, 9).singleNodeValue;
if (x) {
  x.style.color='brown';
  x.style.fontWeight='600';
}
```

My final code is actually more like this:

```
const $e = (xpath) => { return document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, 9).singleNodeValue; }
(x => {if (!x) return; x.style.color='blue'; x.style.fontWeight='900';})($e('//ul[@class="main-menu"]//li[text()="Home"]'));
(x => {if (!x) return; x.style.color='brown'; x.style.fontWeight='600';})($e('//ul[@class="main-menu"]//li[text()="About"]'));
```

While I worked hard to make these one liners, I feel I could do something better.
I leave this to the **gurus** to see if this can be improved upon please.
If not, I'll just run with what I have, it seems to work...

The requirements are:

1. One LONG function needs to be put in only ONCE...  preferably an Xpath, but any function should do.
2. The output of that function needs to be checked and valid before continuing.  (not false, not null)
3. The LONG function can be used several times, in a shortened manner, if output is valid.
4. One line if possible.  More than 80 characters is 'okay', but not much more.
5. Unfortunately, this needs to be done in vanilla javascript.
6. I would prefer to not have to declare any variables.

Thanks.  Enjoy.  I look forward to any answers.

Comment: I don't know anything about you or your history, so take this with a grain of salt, but true professional programmers don't care how many lines their functions take (pre-minification). They do care if their functions are understandable and maintainable, and can be used by later programmers with ease and with as little extra documentation as possible. What you are describing is "code golf". We actually have a site on the Stack Exchange network for that, [codegolf.se], but you should check their [help center](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help) before posting there.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  Readability is not a requirement in this case, just shortness.
I've never heard of Code Golf but it sounds interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Optional Chaining is the best method for me to go with my specific needs.

```
$e('//ul[@class="main-menu"]//li[text()="Home"]')?.style.color='blue';
```

Thanks for watching, wish someone could have suggested it.
I'd thought this could have been a fun one for folks.